# Why doesn't the image in my footer stay inside the container?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website that contains a footer, on the left side just simple text.  On the far right will be icons with links to various social networking sites.  I can't get the icons to stay inside the container when I float the image to the right.  How can I get the image to stay inside the yellow area and out of the green without adding any more padding to the footer?

http://jsfiddle.net/Fd4Pc/1/

```
body {
    background-color: #17241d;
    margin: 0;
}

#mainWindow {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fffff6;
    height:100%;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}

footer, .footer {
    font-size: .8em;
  padding:10px;
}

<body>
<div id="mainWindow">
<p>Text here</p>
<div id="footer">
<footer> 
<span>Left Side</span>
    <img class="right" src="http://static.viewbook.com/images/social_icons/facebook_32.png" />
</footer>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:auto` to your footer:

```
footer, .footer {
    font-size: .8em;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Fd4Pc/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a line-height to your footer: http://jsfiddle.net/Fd4Pc/3/

```
footer, .footer {
    font-size: .8em;
    padding:10px;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

floated element will expand the parent element height, to expand that add float to the parent as well:

```
footer, .footer {
    font-size: .8em;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: That makes the entire footer go outside the container.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways

Add `overflow: hidden` to `footer`

or

clear div that is

```
<footer>

<!--your code goes here-->

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</footer>
```